# Precompiled Handlebars templates in Backbone with Requirejs?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I've been messing around with a backbone.js app using require.js and a handlebars templates (I've added the AMD module stuff to handlebars) and just read that pre-compiling the templates can speed it up a fair bit.

I was wondering how I would go about including the precompiled templates with requirejs. I have a fair few templates to compile (upwards of 15), so i'm not sure if they should all be in the same output file or have their own once compiled. Also, from what it seems, the compiled templates share the same `Handlebars` namespace that the renderer script uses, so I'm not sure how I would go about that when requiring the templates in my files.

Any advice would be awesome!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at the Requirejs-Handlebarsjs plugin: https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work awesomely. I love how it integrates with r.js

Answer (score 17):

A simple approach is to create a RequireJS plugin based on the existing text! plugin. This will load and compile the template. RequireJs will cache and reuse the compiled template.

the plugin code:

```
// hbtemplate.js plugin for requirejs / text.js
// it loads and compiles Handlebars templates
define(['handlebars'],
function (Handlebars) {

    var loadResource = function (resourceName, parentRequire, callback, config) {
        parentRequire([("text!" + resourceName)],
            function (templateContent) {
                var template = Handlebars.compile(templateContent);
                callback(template);
            }
        );
    };

    return {
        load: loadResource
    };

});
```

configuration in main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        handlebars: 'libs/handlebars/handlebars',
        hb: 'libs/require/hbtemplate',
    }
});
```

usage in a backbone.marionette view:

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette',
        'hb!templates/bronnen/bronnen.filter.html',
        'hb!templates/bronnen/bronnen.layout.html'],
        function (Backbone, Marionette, FilterTemplate, LayoutTemplate) {
        ...
```

In case you use the great Backbone.Marionette framework you can
override the default renderer so that it will bypass the builtin
 template loader (for loading/compiling/caching):

```
Marionette.Renderer = {
    render: function (template, data) {
        return template(data);
    }
};
```

Comment: as long as you register them I can't see why it would not work

Comment: I ended up using this technique to good success but I added a twist that helped performance. We wanted to use pre-compiled templates if possible so Grunt.js compiled all our templates into an associative array named JST[] with each one available by the name of the file. It's easy to add something to the above code which checks for the existence of JST and then the specific template within that array. If it's there, return the pre-compiled template. Otherwise do the load as shown and compile it. Then you can develop using many templates you can change at will and use pre-compiled at runtime.

Comment: @JohnMunsch Don't suppose you have any code regarding your solution above? It sounds exactly what I've been working on, but just running into so many issues at the moment I can't seem to get it to work. Would you be keen to share? :)

Comment: @JohnMunsch I would also like to see the code as a plug-in on GitHub if you can share!

Comment: @crawf I asked my former employer if I could release the source code but haven't ever heard anything back. Maybe I can try coding it up again some time soon. The old code was a plugin for RequireJS 1.X anyway so I could improve that at the same time.

Comment: @JohnMunsch That's alright! While I was waiting, I rolled my own version - feel free to comment or use if you like. https://gist.github.com/engram-design/5539338