# How to write a lodash template loader for requirejs

Tags: requirejs, underscore.js, lodash

I'm using a requirejs plugin to define "tmpl!" loader (not a jquery template, but a lodash template. The problem is that the text! loader is adding a ";" at the end of the template. This is being rendered and is breaking everything.

```
(function(global){
  "use strict";
  define({
    load : function(name, require, load, config) {

      var deps = [];

      deps.push('text!' + name);
      deps.push('underscore');

      require(deps, function(source, _) {
        var template = _.template(source);
        load(template);
      });
    }
  });
})(this);
```

How can I stop text! from adding a semi-colon? Or: is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the questions in reverse order:

> is there a better way to do this?

It seems there is an [existing implementation](https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl) of this, and you might want to consider using it rather than writing your own. Although the simple case is a small amount of code, there are a bunch of r.js optimizer-related things you might eventually need.

But regarding your implementation logic, I noticed that [this similar project for Handlebars](https://gist.github.com/engram-design/5539338) does not use the text! plugin but instead does its own XHR in the load() method. This is not explained, but he gives some [guidance for adapting it to other templating languages](https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl). Note: the link came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887512/precompiled-handlebars-templates-in-backbone-with-requirejs) where there is some other good discussion of the approach.

> How can I stop text! from adding a semi-colon?

I tried your plug-in and did not get any added semicolons. Perhaps you could post more of the sample project and templates? Below is mine, with everything in one flat folder for simplicity:

**require.js:** latest from RequireJS site

**domReady.js:** latest from RequireJS site

**text.js:** latest from RequireJS site

**lodash.js:** latest from lodash site

**tmpl.js:** your example loader from the question

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='require.js'></script>
    <script>
    requirejs.config({
        map: {
            '*': { 'underscore': 'lodash' }
        }
    });
    require( [ 'underscore', 'tmpl!friend-template.htm', 'domReady!' ]
        , function( _, friendTemplate ){

        var friendsData = [{ name: 'Bob', age: 35 }, { name: 'Fred', age: 38 }];
        document.body.innerHTML = friendTemplate( {friends: friendsData});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- To be populated dynamically. -->
</body>
</html>
```

**friend-template.htm**:

```
<ul>
    <% _.forEach(friends, function(friend) { %>
    <li>
        <span><%- friend.name %></span>
        <span>( Age: <span class="value"><%- friend.age %></span> )</span>
    </li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a loader specifically for Lo-Dash which you can see here:

https://gist.github.com/tbranyen/6821045

Note: I have no unit tests or assurances this free of bugs, but from my initial testing it appears to work fantastic.

This is better in a number of ways than requirejs-tpl which bakes in it's own implementation which is not exposed.  It also requires a file extension and hardcoded path.  Both of these are configurable in my code.

Edit: I've since released a project called `lodash-template-loader` which has tests.  https://github.com/tbranyen/lodash-template-loader